# No switching of keyboard layout when external usb keyboard is connected | 20.04

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

After connecting an external USB keyboard the keyboard layout did not switch anymore even when the menu showed a different entry. Both keyboards are affected when an external keyboard is attached.
I tried it with 2 different USB keyboards and the effect was the same. After unplugging the USB keyboard and switching the layout in the menu, the changes do take effect again.

Comment: This sounds as a bug. Possibly it's related to [bug #1899206](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1899206). Or you should submit a new one.

Comment: Same problem here. I always have to restart with the keyboard attached.